# Integration of $I=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}e^{-x^2}~dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

It is very easy to calculate the integral of the following,
$$I=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}~dx$$
But is it possible to calculate the following?
$$I=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}e^{-x^2}~dx$$
If we can, how? If we cannot, why?

Comment: Mathematica gives the following result:
$$\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{e}}[I_0(1/2)+I_1(1/2)],$$
where $I_n(z)$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1). Don't ask me how it got there.

Comment: Maybe it expanded $e^{-x^2}$ in a Taylor series, integrated
each term $(-1)^n \sqrt{1-x^2} \, x^{2n} / n!$ (which reduces to
a Beta integral), and recognized the resulting sum as a
combination of Bessel power series.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a trig substitution as you would in the other integral to get

$$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} dt \, \sin^2{t} \, e^{-\cos^2{t}} = \frac12 \int_0^{\pi} dt \, \sin^2{t} \, e^{-\cos^2{t}}$$

then use the half-angle formulae to get

$$I = \frac12 \int_0^{\pi} dt \, \frac12 (1-\cos{2 t}) e^{-(1+\cos{2 t})/2} = \frac1{4 \sqrt{e}}\left [\int_0^{\pi} dt \, e^{-\frac12 \cos{2 t}} -  \int_0^{\pi} dt \,\cos{2 t} \, e^{-\frac12 \cos{2 t}}\right ]$$

The [first integral is simply](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) $\pi I_0(1/2)$; the second is $-\pi I_1(1/2)$.  The result is

$$I = \frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{e}} \left [I_0\left (\frac12\right)+I_1\left (\frac12\right) \right ]$$